# Inconsistency of MySQL syntax errors depending on whether query made from command line or mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

A simple MySQL query is returning a syntax error over *mysqli_connect*, but the identical, copy-pasted query is successful in both the CLI and phpMyAdmin.

Consider this example for MySQL 8.0:

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "USE aTable; INSERT INTO aTable (`aColumn`) VALUES ('aValue');";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

When the PHP runs it prints an error:

> USE aTable; INSERT INTO aTable (`aColumn`) VALUES ('aValue');

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO aTable (`aColumn`) VALUES ('aValue')' at line 1

However when the same query is pasted into phpMyAdmin it tells me:

> 1 row inserted.
> Inserted row id: 6 (Query took 0.0063 seconds.)
> USE aTable; INSERT INTO aTable (`aColumn`) VALUES ('aValue');

**Why are they different?**

Comment: note that for security, you can only have one sql statement per request unless you explicitly use multi_query

Comment: Also note: there is no benefit to use multi_query. It makes your code harder to write, harder to debug, you can't do prepared statements, and it creates a whole class of security vulnerabilities. I never use multi_query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the USE from the PHP code because the database is already selected in the mysqli_connect method.

```
$sql = "USE aTable; INSERT INTO aTable (`aColumn`) VALUES ('aValue');";
```

Should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO aTable (`aColumn`) VALUES ('aValue');";
```

Also, make sure that you're not using the database name in the INSERT query.